# Как написать динамический роут в aiohttp?

Tags: python, асинхронность, router, asyncio

Есть роут вот такой

```
app.router.add_route('GET', '/list/{name}', list)
```

Как можно ним принимать значения ?page=2, если они передаются, а если нету то ?page= в url не появляется?

Answer (score 0):

```
async def get_list(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    ...

...
app.router.add_get('/', get_list)
```